# Getting user information from Google Sign In

Tags: android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I'm afraid I'm a bit lost. I have successfully integrated a Google sign-in into my app. However, I'm looking for a little more information about the user than the usual `name`, `email` and `photoUrl`.

For example, Facebook allows developers to get user liked pages and such. Is similar information available in Google APIs?

I'm not looking for any specific information - currently I need to see what I can access and what I cannot. Trying to weigh the pros and cons between the two logins (Facebook and Google) when it comes to showing relevant content to the user in the app based on the user profile.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

That information retrieval is outlined below:

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = 

GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
if (acct != null) {
  String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
  String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
  String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
  String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
  String personId = acct.getId();
  Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
}
```

And described here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people

Comment: Yup, I got this. I'm looking for a bit more based on which I can provide relevant content to the user. Sorta like maybe location, likes etc. Imaging stuff you'd put in a recommendation system. Yup. that stuff

Comment: The docs only show access to simple information like listed above: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount

Answer (score 0):

You can't get other information as it is against the privacy policy. When user sign up in a app using google it shows app can only access basic information nothing more. That's why you will be not able to access other critical information, like what site user is visiting , what he likes and dislikes on youtube etc etc.

Google sign up option  is there to collect data for google, not to give you ;-)

But yes, you can get location using location api provided by google.

Answer (score 0):

```
val acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(requireContext())                                
if (acct != null) {
  val personName = acct.displayName
  val personGivenName = acct.givenName
  val personFamilyName = acct.familyName
  val personEmail = acct.email
  val personId = acct.id
  val personPhoto = acct.photoUrl
  val IDToken = acct.idToken
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).